# Creating matching/search functions in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link to jsfiddle with all the code

https://jsfiddle.net/f45gfx2p/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- This is standard HTML code that tells the browser it is a HTML page-->
<html lang="en-GB"> <!-- This tells the browser what language html is using-->
<head> <!-- standard html tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Any Phone4You</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
<h1>Any Phone4You</h1>
</header>
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="search">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select phone brand</legend>
            <label for="sony">Sony</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Sony">
            <label for="motorola">Motorola</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Motorola">
            <label for="samsung">Samsung</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Samsung">
            <label for="apple">Apple</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="Apple">
            <label for="lg">LG</label>
            <input type="radio" name="brand" class="phone" value="LG">
        </fieldset>
        <label for="phone_model">Model</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone_model" />
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select a network</legend>
            <label for="zmobile">Z-Mobile</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="Z-Mobile">
            <label for="o3">O3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="O3">
            <label for="fodavone">Fodavone</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="Fodavone">
            <label for="nn">NN</label>
            <input type="radio" name="net" class="network" value="NN">
        </fieldset>
        <input type="range" name="rating" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="50" id="range.slider" />
        <span id="range">0</span><br /><br />
        <label for="text_m">Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text_m" />
        <label for="internet">Data</label>
        <input type="text" id="internet" />
        <label for="upcost">Upfront Cost</label>
        <input type="number" id="upcost" />
        <label for="month_cost">Monthly Cost</label>
        <input type="number" id="month_cost" />
        <label for="contract_length">Contract Length</label>
        <input type="number" id="contract_length" />
        <input type="button" value="click me" id="login">
    </form>
</div>
<footer>@Copyright Reserved by Przemyslaw Wojtas @2015-2016 !Do not copy!</footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.margin{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.textalign{
    text-align: left;
}
.textalign2{
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    top: 2%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(39,133,203);
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;

}
h1{
    left: 5%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: 0;
}
.main{
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(98,204,255);
}
.search{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(39,133,203);
    opacity: 0.9;
}
footer{
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif; 
}
fieldset{
    display: block;
}
form{
        font-size: 16px;
    width:100%;
        border: 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}/* this will style my form */
input, select, textarea{
        display: block;
        margin:2%;
}/* this style all input, select and textarea tags */
input{
    border:2px solid #CCC;
    width: 70%;
        margin-top: 2%;
}/* further styling to input tag */
textarea{
    width:50%;
    border:3px solid #CCC;
}/* further styling to textarea tag */

/*
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 200px;
*/
```

JS:

```
/*
var brand=["Motorola","Nokia","Apple","Apple","Samsung","Samsung","LG","Nokia","LG","Sony","Sony"];
var model=["StarTAC","3310","iPhone 5C","iPhone 5C","Galaxy S5","Galaxy S5","G3","Lumia 925","Optimus L7 2","Xperia Z3","Xperia Z3"];
var network=["Z-Mobile","O3","Fodavone","NN","O3","Fodavone","NN","Fodavone","NN","O3","NN"];
var minutes=["300","100","300","1000","500","600","1000","600","250","Unlimited","Unlimited"];
var texts=["3500","5000","Unlimited","Unlimited","Unlimited","Unlimited","Unlimited","Unlimited","5000","Unlimited","Unlimited"];
var data=["N/A","N/A","250MB","2GB","500MB","1GB","1GB","500MB","500MB","1GB","10GB"];
var ucost=["0","0","0","49","0","0","0","0","0","79","0"];
var mcost=["5","2","22","34","24","27","31","27","12","38","44"];
var length=["24","24","24","18","24","24","24","18","24","24","24"];
*/
function phoneContract(brand, model, network, minutes, texts, data, upcost, monthlycost, length) {
    this.brand=brand;
    this.model=model;
    this.network=network;
    this.minutes=minutes;
    this.texts=texts;
    this.data=data;
    this.upcost=upcost;
    this.monthlycost=monthlycost;
    this.length=length;
}
var contract=[];
contract.push(new phoneContract("Motorola", "StarTAC", "Z-Mobile", "300", "3500", "N/A", "0", "5", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Nokia", "3310", "O3", "100", "5000", "N/A", "0", "2", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Apple", "iPhone 5C", "Fodavone", "300", "Unlimited", "250MB", "0", "22", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Apple", "iPhone 5C", "NN", "1000", "Unlimited", "2GB", "49", "34", "18"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Samsung", "Galaxy S5", "O3", "500", "Unlimited", "500MB", "0", "24", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Samsung", "Galaxy S5", "Fodavone", "600", "Unlimited", "1GB", "0", "27", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("LG", "G3", "NN", "1000", "Unlimited", "1GB", "0", "31", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Nokia", "Lumia 925", "Fodavone", "600", "Unlimited", "500MB", "0", "27", "18"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("LG", "Optimus L7 2", "NN", "250", "5000", "500MB", "0", "12", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Sony", "Xperia Z3", "O3", "Unlimited", "Unlimited", "1GB", "79", "38", "24"));
contract.push(new phoneContract("Sony", "Xperia Z3", "NN", "Unlimited", "Unlimited", "10GB", "0", "44", "24"));

function checkBrand(){
    var phone
    var brandCheck;
    phone = document.getElementsByClassName("phone");
    for (var i=0;i<phone.length;i++) {
        console.log(phone[i].checked)
        if (phone[i].checked == true) {
            brandCheck = phone[i].value;
        }   
    }
    return brandCheck;
}

function checkNetwork(){
    var network
    var networkCheck
    network = document.getElementsByClassName("network");
    for (var i=0;i<network.length;i++) {
        console.log(network[i].checked)
        if (network[i].checked == true) {
        networkCheck = network[i].value;
        }
    }
    return networkCheck;
}
var button = document.getElementById("login");
button.addEventListener("click", search, false);
var minutes
function slidefunction() {
    minutes = parseInt(slider.value)
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes";
    console.log(minutes);
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range.slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", slidefunction, false);


function search() {
 var brandCheck=checkBrand();
 var networkCheck=checkNetwork();
var model
model = document.getElementById("phone_model"); //???
var e
e = document.getElementById("text_m"); //checkbox
var f
f = document.getElementById("internet"); //checkbox
var g
g = document.getElementById("upcost");  //auto
var h
h = document.getElementById("month_cost"); //auto ask
var i
i = document.getElementById("contract_length"); //dropdown
    for (var p=0;p<contract.length;p++) {
    if (brandCheck == contract[p].brand &&
        model.value == contract[p].model &&
        networkCheck == contract[p].network &&
        minutes >= contract[p].minutes &&
        e.value == contract[p].texts &&
        f.value == contract[p].data &&
        g.value == contract[p].upcost &&
        h.value == contract[p].monthlycost &&
        i.value == contract[p].length) {
    document.write(contract[p].brand + " " + contract[p].model + " " + contract[p].network + " " + contract[p].minutes + " " + contract[p].texts + " " +  contract[p].data + " " + contract[p].upcost + " " + contract[p].monthlycost + " " + contract[p].length + " " + "</br>" );
    }
  }
}
```

Basically this application only works if it matches all information from the array, but I would like to work so that for example if it matches few on the options for example model brand and network and display it's results according to that match so for example display all the phones that are from Motorola etc. Also I would like to give match % so how good that match is :) How would that be done

Answer (score 1):

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/f45gfx2p/2/

```
for (var p=0;p<contract.length;p++) {
    if (brandCheck == contract[p].brand &&
        model.value == contract[p].model &&
        networkCheck == contract[p].network &&
        minutes >= contract[p].minutes &&
        e.value == contract[p].texts &&
        f.value == contract[p].data &&
        g.value == contract[p].upcost &&
        h.value == contract[p].monthlycost &&
```

In your code above, you are using `'and' &&` operators - which means that everything has to match - model.value has to match and networkCheck has to match and .... so on and so on.
Switch these to `'or' ||` operators and you can have a variety of matches. model.value matches or networkCheck matches. Or you can combine them however you see fit.

```
var percentage = 0; //create a percentage variable
if(e.value){ //check if user has selected a form element
    percentage += 1; //if an element is selected add one to percentage
}
//if a user selects 4 elements out of 8 then percentage is 50%
percentage = Math.floor((percentage / 8) * 100)); //get percentage as a percentage rather than fraction
for (var p=0;p<contract.length;p++) {
        if (brandCheck == contract[p].brand ||  //<---or instead of and
            model.value == contract[p].model ||
            networkCheck == contract[p].network ||
            minutes >= contract[p].minutes ||
            e.value == contract[p].texts ||
            f.value == contract[p].data ||
            g.value == contract[p].upcost ||
            h.value == contract[p].monthlycost ||
```

On the match percentage front - check to see how many values there are and how many matches have been made out of those values. So if `g.value == contract[p].upcost` returns true thats 1 out of 8 matched etc.

Comment: oh yeah so simple I didn't notice that, obviously these results will be in a form in the box right next to the search bar, but I want the search to work properly first, and how about inserting a percentage based on the result so let's say if I match all I get 100% but if I match half of them then give it 50% //edit btw now my radio buttons do not work correctly, only the first radio button works, if I choose for example O3 as a network on it's own, function doesn't work

Comment: and how would that match percentage front code look like, I only started working with js a month ago but I want to make sure that this website is really good, just give me an example and I will figure it out :) edit// and yes it is working now :)